# Как отправить email через нестандартное приложение?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

Есть ли механизм, который проверяет наличие рабочих почтовых клиентов, чтобы отправить письмо, если пользователь неавторизован в дефолтной почте на устройстве?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно настроить кастомную URL-схему для каждого клиента, к примеру, Gmail:

> googlegmail://

Для других можно посмотреть их схемы.

Затем можете проверить кто сможет открыть:

```
NSString *gmailURL = @"googlegmail://";

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL gmailURL]]) {
    //Можете добавить, к примеру, кнопку, по нажатию на которую откроется Gmail клиент.
} else {
    //Не установлен
}
//нажатие на кнопку, открываем в Gmail клиенте:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:gmailURL]];
//аналогично для других, у яндекса вроде yandexmail://
```

Comment: Если какой нибудь почтовый клиент не настроил доступ к себе по URL схемам, могу ли я как то иначе с ним взаимодействовать?